# Zombie check on Transaction - How to reproduce it?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I get SqlTransaction.Zombie exception in production(In .NET Windows application not ASP.NET application). I got answer in below article how and when the exception is thrown. In production one server application available which perform DB operation and there could be more than one client applications to interact with server.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccesstechnologies/archive/2010/08/24/zombie-check-on-transaction-error-this-sqltransaction-has-completed-it-is-no-longer-usable.aspx

In the article, it is given that connection is explicitly closed. My question is in real world application what are the possibilities to close the connection (in few cases only it occurs in production)? I would like to hear the possible scenarios to reproduce it.

One of the servers is getting stopped due to the Exception. Please do help.

Is there possibility for SPs to close the connection unexpectedly? If so, please do describe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, the *exact same* bug/issue occurs in real [buggy] code. Don't close a resource that is going to be accessed: it doesn't matter if it's a database connection or a file stream. That's the long and short of it. **That is, *what* is the question?** This error can be minimized with `using` and better lifetime management. Also, because connections are generally *cheap* with connection pooling I would advise against holding onto a connection outside of the call-stack without good reason.

Comment: I'm working in existing application. I'm looking for possible reasons to close the connection either from .NET code or from SQL side. In the given article, they have closed the connection explicitly. In real world cases, what are the possible cases?